# how to plot a graph in wherever of a table

Tags: plot

how to plot a graph in wherever of a table like in a `\multicolumn` or `\multirow` cell? I tried tikz package, but the coordinate of the tools like draw was hard to be fixed. BTW, I found the manual of tikz pgf was so long and so hard to be understood:-).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you have tried so far and even a little example of the desired output (a photo of something handwritten if enough).

Comment: Regarding the TikZ-manual, start by reading the tutorials in chapters 2-6. I don't quite understand your comment about coordinates. The coordinates in a `tikzpicture` is only relative to other things in the diagram, not the table or the page, what do you mean by "fixed"? There should be no problem with having a `tikzpicture` environment in a table cell.